# Could not find Dart in your Flutter SDK

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I've been developing a Flutter app for a while. Since the last update I am getting this message:

> Could not find Dart in your Flutter SDK. Please run 'flutter doctor'
>   in the terminal then reload the project once all issues are resolved.

I can't run my application in vs-code right now. When I run `flutter doctor` in terminal, everything seems to be fine.

```
[00:26:17] [General] [Info] Searching for SDKs...
[00:26:17] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\system32
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\MinGW\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\src\flutter\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Android\tools
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Androidplatform-tools
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info] Found Flutter project at C:\Users\yugiyuu\Desktop\FindMeReal\FindMeReal:
            Mobile? true
            Web? false
            Create Trigger? false
            Flutter Repo? false
[00:26:17] [General] [Info] Searching for flutter.bat
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     Looking for flutter.bat in:
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\Desktop\FindMeReal\FindMeReal
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\Desktop\FindMeReal\FindMeReal\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\Desktop\FindMeReal\FindMeReal\.flutter
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\Desktop\FindMeReal\FindMeReal\.flutter\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\Desktop\FindMeReal\FindMeReal\vendor\flutter
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\Desktop\FindMeReal\FindMeReal\vendor\flutter\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\MinGW\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Android\tools
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Android\tools\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Androidplatform-tools
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Androidplatform-tools\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter for flutter.bat
[00:26:17] [General] [Info] Searching for dart.exe
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart.exe in:
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\MinGW\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Android\tools
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Android\tools\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Androidplatform-tools
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Androidplatform-tools\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[00:26:17] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path undefined for dart.exe
```

This is my log.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale tr-TR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.45.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

And this is my `flutter doctor` output.

Dart Version:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is your output when you run `dart --version` in the terminal?

Comment: " 'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: You have to install the `dart SDK`.

Comment: I posted an answer. Check it out.

Comment: @T.TSage Are you certain that `dart` needs to be globally available? I think it should be enough to have it installed locally in the flutter folder.

Comment: Go to your `terminal` and navigate to where your `flutter1 directory is. When inside the directory, run `dart --version` and let's see the output @umutişgördü

Comment: I added to question.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1212) could help.

Answer (score 3):

The solution worked for me.

go to directory where your flutter sdk is located.
and navigate to
C:/flutterSDKDir/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin

copy url

create new system variable path and paste url their.
It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by delete flutter folder and downloaded it again

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps.

1. Go to directory where your flutter sdk is located.
2. Navigate to `C:\flutter_windows_3.10.1-stable\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin`.
3. Copy this path `C:\flutter_windows_3.10.1-stable\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin` and paste it on top of your environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have two copies of the Flutter SDK:

- C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter
- C:\src\flutter

VS Code is picking the first one (posisbly you have that set in `dart.flutterSdkPath`?). My guess is that when you're running "flutter doctor" from the terminal, you're running the second one.

If you run "C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor" from the terminal, it will probably download the Dart SDK and fix the issue, but it would be better to eliminate one of the copies of the SDK to avoid confusion.

**Edit**: Actually, it looks like your Dart SDK might be incomplete, since dart.exe appears to have been found, but the folder is being filtered out - I suspect because it does not have the analysis_server snapshot. Try deleting the "bin/cache/dart-sdk" folder from the Flutter SDK and then running "C:\Users\yugiyuu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor" (or deleting that copy of the SDK if you want to use the other).

If it still doesn't work, please raise an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code and we can figure it out (and perhaps improve the reporting).

Answer (score 0):

C:\src\flutter\bin Add this type URL in Path (User Variables) in Environment Variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but then I got the solution (Windows 11)
01 March 2024 - Updated

1. The flutter SDK you downloaded on the website (https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/mobile?tab=download) should manually located in :
2. (C:\Users<*YOUR COMPUTER USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp)
3. Once the Flutter SDK has been moved there, that's good
4. Lauch VsCode
5. Crtl + Shift + P
6. Select -> (Flutter: New Project)
7. Done <<<<

Hope that Helps :)